# Questions about distributing $k$ objects to $n$ recipients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Rule: Distributions of $k$ objects to $n$ recipients can be done in $n^k$ ways with no restrictions and $n!$ ways when each recipient receives exactly one object.

Obvious Examples:

1. In how many ways can we distribute $70$ computers to $6$ schools s.t. no two  schools share a computer? The schools are recipients so for each computer we choose one of six  schools which can be done in $6^{70}$  ways by product rule.
2. In how many ways can we permute the word "house"? Each word has five places like this: __ __ __ __ __. And each place can receive any one of h, o, u, s, e. So for each letter we choose a place in one of $5, 4, 3, 2, 1$ ways so that there are $5!$ permutations by product rule.

Confusing example:

1. How many PINs of length four are there if each symbol in a PIN is chosen from the $26$ uppercase letters in the Roman alphabet and the ten digits?

This below is how I thought about the confusing example:

Let __ __ __ __ represent an arbitrary PIN where __ is a recipient. Then by the rule above, for every symbol we choose one of four places. But the problem is that after the fourth symbol we run out of places for symbols. Also, the answer given for this problem is $36^4$ which means the symbols are the recipients, not the places in a PIN.

My questions:

In problems like those above, how do we know which objects are recipients and which ones are receivables(receive-ees?) ? Also, in what way is the confusing example above different from the other two problems? Thanks.

Comment: Your rule has a lot of assumptions hidden inside of it; specifically, that the objects are distinguishable (so that it is not the same thing to get the first object as to get the second object), and that the recipients are distinguishable (so that, in your first example, not only can you distinguish the computers from one another, but also the schools).

Comment: In your example, the “recipients” are the characters of the PIN, as you correctly note (the fours spaces). The “objects” are what you can put into the spaces, namely, the alphanumerical characters that can comprise the PIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One recipient can receive  more than one object, but one object can't  go to more than one recipient.  Similarly a character can be placed at more than once positions,hence it is a recipient, while a position can't  have more than one characters, hence it is analogous to the object. 
Now, each of the $4$ objects (in our case, positions) can go to any of the $36$ recipients (in our case, characters) . Thus  the total no. of ways of such distribution is $36^4$.

Comment: Suppose places in the confusing problem are recipients and the symbols are objects. But each place in a __ __ __ __cannot receive more than a single symbol. Contradiction. I see. Thanks. I wish textbooks were a bit more mindful when it comes to explaining such intricacies.